Get siunitx output in bold when using Cambria Math font
When trying to get units in bold using the siunitx package \textbf{\unit{\kg,\um, \mJ}}, I get the warning

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/CambriaMath(5)/b/n' undefined


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

However when using $\mathbf{kg,\mu m,mJ}$ it works (after specifying mathbf=sym and ignoring the \mu being italicised).
My MWE
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}

\setsansfont{Verdana}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathrm{Cambria Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily{\mufont}{Cambria Math} 
\DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\ensuremath{\mufont μ}}{-6} 

\begin{document}

\textbf{\unit{\kg,\um, mJ}}\\
$\mathbf{kg, \mu m,mJ}$\\
\textbf{\qty{100}{\um}}\\
$\mathbf{100\, \mu m}$

\end{document}

I'm using MiKTeX and compiling with LuaLaTeX. How do I get the output produced by siunitx to be in bold when needed?
